# Trying to add rows to a datatable within a dataset but editor doesn't "see" my dataset/datatable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a dataset (DataSet1) defined in the dataset screen in VS2010.  It contains a datatable (DataTable1):

[image]

Shouldn't I be able to access this datatable now in my program, like this?:

```
DataTable1.Rows.Add("Mark","123 Anystreet","555-512-2333","mark@bazinga.com")
```

When I try to do the above code, the editor acts like it has no idea what DataTable1 is, even though I have created it in the dataset screen.  I don't want to bind the datatable to a datasource, since the data will be provided programatically (this is just a test program).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you declared an instance of the dataset?
just creating the dataset in the editor is not enough. basically all you have done is designed what the dataset "looks" like.  the tables and the columns in those tables, along with the data type (and other assorted properties) of each column.

typically, you create an instance of  your (typed) `dataset` somewhere in your code...

```
MyDataSet ds = new MyDataSet();
```

then, add your rows to the instance of the table....

```
DataTable1.Rows.Add("Mark","123 Anystreet","555-512-2333","mark@bazinga.com")
```

Comment: Thanks, Muad'Dib!  I was assuming that if I created the dataset in design view, that the code editor/compiler would know about it.  Thanks for setting me straight!  Also, I got my question answered by the Kwisatz Haderach!  How cool is that? ;-)

Comment: You would also have to say, in your case, `ds.Tables.Add(DataTable1);`

Comment: Yep, you're right Bryan.  I'm actually familiar with defining datasets and datatables within the code.  I was just trying out the dataset designer and was hoping that it would be like the UI designer.  With the UI designer, I can add a button and the editor knows about it (button1.Text = "Print").  But, it appears it doesn't work that way with the dataset designer.  I was hoping I could create it visually, then add the columns and they would be available to me within the code.  I wish it worked that way!